# Do Carmo Riemannian Geometry, chapter 0. Definition 2.1.

Tags: differential-geometry, definition

> A *differentiable manifold* of dimension $n$ is a set $M$ and a family of injective mappings $x_\alpha : U_\alpha \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to M$ of open sets $U_\alpha$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that:
>
> 1) $\bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha = M$.
>
> 2) For any pair $\alpha,\beta$, with $x_\alpha(U_\alpha) \cap x_\beta (U_\beta) = W \neq \emptyset$, the sets $x^{-1}_\alpha(W)$ and $x^{-1}_\beta(W)$ are open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the mappings $x_\beta^{-1} \circ x_\alpha$ are differentiable.
>
> 3) The family $\left\{(U_\alpha,x_\alpha )\right\}$ is maximal relative to condition 1) and 2).

What does maximality mean in this context?

Comment: @user647486: That's not quite correct. For instance, on $\mathbf R$, there are two distinct smooth structures contained in different maximal atlases, one generated by the global chart $(\mathbf R, \mathrm{Id})$ and another generated by $(\mathbf R,x\mapsto x^3)$. These are not compatible smooth structures since $x\mapsto x^{1/3}$ is not differentiable everywhere it is defined.

Answer (score 3):

Maximality in this context means that if $\{(V_\beta,y_\beta)\}$ is another collection of injective mappings $y_\beta$ and open sets $V_\beta$ such that $\bigcup_\beta V_\beta = M$, and such that for each $\alpha$ and each $\beta$, the mappings $x_\alpha\circ y_\beta^{-1}$ and $y_\beta\circ x_\alpha^{-1}$ are differentiable where they are defined, then $\{(V_\beta,y_\beta)\}\subset\{(U_\alpha,x_\alpha)\}$.

Another way of stating maximality is to say that the collection $\{(U_\alpha,x_\alpha)\}$ contains every chart $(V,y)$ that is compatible with $(U_\alpha,x_\alpha)$ for each $\alpha$.